# Hierarchical Numbering of Listings with \captionof

Tags: numbering, listings, captions, minted

I'm using the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package to add captions to listings produced with `\inputminted`. E.g.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first chapter}

\captionof{listing}{some code}
\begin{minted}{C}
#define X 1
\end{minted}

\chapter{The second chapter}

\captionof{listing}{some more code}
\begin{minted}{C}
#define Y 2
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

This seems to be the only way to add captions to listings produced by minted that still allows listings to span multiple pages. What annoys me greatly is that I am not able to figure out how to number the resulting listings hierarchically. They show up as `Listing 1` and `Listing 2` but I'd rather have them numbered `Listing 1.1`, `Listing 2.1` and so forth according to the chapter they are in (akin to numbering of floats). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\captionof{listing}{...}` uses the macro `\thelisting` in order to show the listing number. If this should be changed and the listing number reset by chapter number use `\counterwithin{listing}{chapter}` from `chngcntr` package (or after the LaTeX kernel update, it is contained in the Kernel)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}% Only needed unless using new LaTeX kernel update from early of April 2018
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{minted}
\counterwithin{listing}{chapter}
%\renewcommand{\thelisting}{\thechapter.\arabic{listing}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first chapter}



\captionof{listing}{some code}
\begin{minted}{C}
#define X 1
\end{minted}

\chapter{The second chapter}

\captionof{listing}{some more code}
\begin{minted}{C}
#define Y 2
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!